# Is it possible to make this discord bot tell info about Minecraft servers depending on what the user writes in the command other then just one server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was wondering if it was possible to make it so that you can have the bot search for more than one server when putting in the command.
for example !mc server.com

bot: server.com
playercount: ?/?
other info

```
onst { Client, Intents, Message} = require('discord.js');
const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
const {EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');
const options = {
    timeout: 1000 * 5, 
    enableSRV: true 
};
const prefix = "!mcstatus"; 
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        "Guilds",
        "GuildMessages",
        "MessageContent"
    ]
});
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot started');
    
    client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: `${server_ip}`, type: 'WATCHING' }], status: 'active' });
});
const server_ip = "mc.hypixel.net"; 
const server_port = 25565; 
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
          util.status(server_ip, server_port, options)
    .then((result) => {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#FF0000")
    .setTitle("mcdonalds")
    .setDescription(`This will show the status and info about the minecraft server \n **Server ip:** ${server_ip} \n **Server port:** ${server_port}`)
    .addFields(
        {name:"Server Version", value: `${result.version.name}`},
        {name:"Server Protocol Version", value:`${result.version.protocol}`},
        {name:"Players Online", value:`${result.players.online}`},
        {name:"Max Players", value:`${result.players.max}`},
        {name:"MOTD (May Not Display Accurately)", value:`${result.motd.clean}`},
        {name:"Latency", value:`${result.roundTripLatency}`},
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    })
    
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#808080")
    .setTitle("mcdonalds")
    .setDescription(`The server was unable to be pinged or you mis-typed the info`)
    .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    
    })}});
client.login("okent");
```

if there is a way this would be very cool

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.prototype.split()` method to turn your string into an array of strings, for example:

```js
let args = message.content.split(" "); // Splitting with a blank space.

        args = args.slice(1); // Remove the first argument which would be the command itself.

        const server_port = 25565; // Leave the default port for MC servers.
        
        if (args.length < 1) return message.reply("Didn't provide arguments.")
// Run a forEach loop for every argument.
        args.forEach((arg) => {
          util
            .status(arg, server_port, options)
            .then((result) => {
              const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#FF0000")
                .setTitle("Results")
                .setDescription(
                  `This will show the status and info about the minecraft server \n **Server ip:** ${arg} \n **Server port:** ${server_port}`
                )
                .addFields(
                  { name: "Server Version", value: `${result.version.name}` },
                  {
                    name: "Server Protocol Version",
                    value: `${result.version.protocol}`,
                  },
                  { name: "Players Online", value: `${result.players.online}` },
                  { name: "Max Players", value: `${result.players.max}` },
                  {
                    name: "MOTD (May Not Display Accurately)",
                    value: `${result.motd.clean}`,
                  },
                  { name: "Latency", value: `${result.roundTripLatency}` }
                )
                .setTimestamp();

              message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#808080")
                .setTitle("Error")
                .setDescription(
                  `${arg} was unable to be pinged or you mis-typed the info`
                )
                .setTimestamp();
              message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
            });
        });
```

(Make sure to review the code before pasting it in)

The snippet above simply splits the message.content string into an array of strings then runs a loop for each string in the array which runs the util status check and then returns a new embed, or an error.

Make sure to mark this as the answer if it helped.

Comment: how do you add the code in like what part because I'm getting confused

Comment: The snippet above uses the message object which means it has to be somewhere under the messageCreate event.

Comment: could you maybe do the exact line of code its under because im getting errors like BITFIELD_INVALID and have no idea how to fix it